# RESTful convention to manage items and types of items

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5

I have a database with two tables: Type and Item.

Each Item has a Type (so in the Item table there is a field named `type_id`).

I need to create an **REST api** to manage those items but I'm struggling to define the URL structure for it.

My initial approach is:

`POST` `/api/type` Creates a new type.

`PUT` `/api/type/id` Updates an existing type.

Then for the items:

`POST` `/api/items/typeId` To create a new item and relate it to the type.

`PUT` `/api/items/typeId/itemId` To update the item.

The problem that I can see with this is, after an item is created, it looks like I cannot change its type, so I changed it to this:

`POST` `api/type/typeId/item` To create a new item.

`PUT` `api/items/itemId` To update an existing item.

But it doesn't seem right (lack of consistency?).

Any help, please? What is the convention to manage `parent/children` items?

Comment: Take alook at this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Take alook at this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Thanks @MahdiYounesi. Unfortunately that doesn't help. I know how to do it for a single resource. My problem is when I have a relationship as explained in the question, I don't know what should be the structure of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Just because `item` is related to `type`, it does not live in a hierarchical structure below type, especially if the relation can be changed. See it as a flat structure:

```
POST /api/item
PUT /api/item/{itemId}
```

where the item's `typeID` is just one of the POST/PUT parameters.

Where it makes sense to use hierarchical URLs is for retrieving data. For example

```
GET /api/type/{typeId}/items
```

lists all items of this type.

Note: I used the singular form `item` instead of `items` in POST/PUT for consistency reasons. You only send one item at a time. While when retrieving, you retrieve multiple items.